# Daily Coding Problem, 1.4: Running time given in the solution incorrect?

Tags: algorithm, performance

---

**PREAMBLE**:

I am working on a particular puzzle in a book named Daily Coding Problem. It is the fourth problem in the first chapter.

**The problem statement is:**

```
Given an array of integers, return a new array where each element 
in the new array list is the number of smaller elements to the 
right of that element in the original input array.
```

They propose the naive solution, which is to iterate through the elements right of each element in the array and count appropriately. This, of course, is O(n^2) time.

They claim, however, that there is a solution that runs in O(nlogn) time. So for a few days now I have been scratching my head over it. Finally, out of impatience and and frustration, having come up with a few different solutions, none of which improve on O(n^2), I looked at their solution.

---

**MY QUESTION:**

Their solution was exactly one of the solutions I had come up with. But, when I consider the runtime of this solution, I find that is O(n^2) time and not O(long) time, as they claim it to be.

I would like your input :)

**The algorithm:**

1. Iterate backwards over the input list
2. Maintain a sorted list of the elements so far seen
3. Look at the current element to see where it would fit into the sorted array that is under construction as we proceed from back to front.

**The "analysis:"**

For every element in an n-element array,

1. The algorithm searches the sorted array under construction not find the place of that element, O(logn)
2. That element is inserted into the array, O(n) (the entire sorted array that is being constructed may have to be shifted).

So, for every element in an n-element array, the operations of searching for the proper place of that element and inserting that element into sorted array under construction would be O(logn + n) = O(n), and, hence, the entire algorithm would be O(n * n).

For example, if we are given the array

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

the insertion of every element into the sorted array we are maintaining (constructing) would require a shift.

Am I incorrect?

Thanks for your time and feedback :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re right but not if you use a binary heap for inserting. Essentially doing a sort of heap-sort along the way.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

The insert operation is O(logn) at worst and after that your last inserted element becomes the root of a subtree which has the property that all the elements from the subtree are smaller than the root.

The binary heap is usually used to implement a priority queue.

A more straightforward solution is to use an indirect index to sort the array. The index will give you the number of elements smaller at the right of the current element because those are the elements that keep the current element out of position in the unsorted array with exactly count positions.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int arr[6] = {8, 1, 3, 10, 5, 6};
//int arr[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
vector<int> a(begin(arr), end(arr));
 // sort using a custom function object
struct {
    bool operator()(int idx1, int idx2) const
    {   
        return a[idx1] < a[idx2];
    }   
} custom_compare;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<int> idx(a.size(), 0);
    vector<int> result(a.size(), 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        idx[i] = i;
    }
    sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(), custom_compare);
    for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result[idx[i]] = i - idx[i];
        result[idx[i]] = result[idx[i]] < 0 ? 0 : result[idx[i]];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        cout << result[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For the simple example the idx will look like the following:

```
1 2 4 5 0 3
```

So element a[1] = 1 should be in position 0, element a[2] = 3 should be in position 1 and so on. If we look at element 0, that is in position 4 in the sorted array and in position 0 in the unsorted array, so there are four elements smaller than 8, keeping 8, 4 positions apart from its place in the sorted array. Of course we get negative numbers for numbers that are out of position but because bigger numbers are in front, but we just set these to 0.

And the result will look like the following after running the program:

```
4 0 0 2 0 0
```

So 8 has 4 elements smaller than him at the right, and 10 has 2.

Comment: Hey @CristianBidea. If I may post here a late follow up question. Inserting is, as you say, O(logn). However, I also need to check where the newly inserted value is located with respect to any values in the heap that are smaller than it -- that is, the values in the subtree **rooted by the newly inserted element.** Would this not be O(n), as I have to iterate through the entire sub tree that is rooted by the newly inserted element and count the size of that subtree?

Comment: I don’t think I understand the questions. The subtree is known after the insert by using the formulas of binary heap indices (2i and 2i+1 are children of ith node)

Comment: Hey Cristian! Excuse me if I wasn’t clear. My question was: don’t I have to traverse the sub tree to count how many nodes are in the sub tree, for the problem solution says to “measure the place of the newly inserted element with respect to elements less than it.”

Comment: Yes, but you can cache the counting of elements. A node has count = count(subtree left) + count( subtree right). The counts can be cached when the binary heap is constructed.